# Hierarchical sum of the columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have got one problem as follows:

```
ID NAME  AMOUNT PARENTID  
1  Adam  1000   0  
2  John  2000   1  
3  Clark 1500   2  
4  Rita  1200   3  
5  jack  1600   3  
6  mark  1800   2  
7  Finn  1500   6  
8  Ryan  1100   6
```

So the **data above is the result of a query with multiple joins**
and it is a kind of hierarchy or tree something like this:

```
       1  
       |  
       2  
     /  \   
   3      6  
  / \     / \  
5   4    7   8
```

and now I need to modify my query so that I get the following result

```
ID NAME  AMOUNT PARENTID  DownstreamSum   
1  Adam  1000   0         10700     
2  John  2000   1         8700      
3  Clark 1500   2         2800      
4  Rita  1200   3         0         
5  jack  1600   3         0         
6  mark  1800   2         2600      
7  Finn  1500   6         0          
8  Ryan  1100   6         0
```

So the logic is that the parent should have the sum of all the downstream child nodes in the `DownstreamSum` column.

for example:

- id 6 should have the sum of amount of id 7 and 8
- id 3 should have the sum of amount of id 4 and 5

but id 2 should have the sum of the amount of id 3 and the sum of amount of id 4 and 5

I tried with many possibilities with `partition by` and `group by` but I was not able to get the desired output.

Comment: Oracle 11gR2 or newer, or older one?

Comment: I had a similar question a couple of years back, but I needed a child attribute count, not a sum. I asked it on Asktom, the answer might be of use to you too: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536677100346820855 Get ready for a long read

Answer (score 5):

Here is the query, please check.

[SQL fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a0b3/51)

```
SELECT  Y.*, X.TOTAL_AMOUNT FROM (
    WITH hierarchy (PARENTID, ID) AS (SELECT PARENTID, ID
        FROM Hierarchy_result
        UNION ALL
        SELECT h.PARENTID, bs.ID
        FROM Hierarchy_result  bs, hierarchy  h WHERE bs.PARENTID=h.ID)
        SELECT h.PARENTID AS PARENTID,
        --SUM(FR.AMOUNT)
        /*SUM((CASE WHEN FR.ID=h.PARENTID
            THEN FR.amount
            ELSE 0.0 END))*/
        SUM(FR.amount) TOTAL_AMOUNT
    FROM hierarchy h, Hierarchy_result FR WHERE FR.ID=h.ID
    GROUP BY h.PARENTID 
    ORDER BY h.PARENTID) X, Hierarchy_result Y WHERE X.PARENTID(+) = Y.ID ORDER BY Y.ID;
```

Comment: Good answer. I would use modern join syntax but, apart from that, it's good. +1

Comment: Indeed nice one!

Answer (score 4):

A typical recursive CTE (available since Oracle 11gR2) will allow you to walk the branches to the leaves. Then a simple `SUM()` gives you the result you want. For example:

```
with
n (root_id, current_id, name, amount, parentid) as (
  select id, id, name, amount, parentid from t
 union all
  select n.root_id, t.id, t.name, t.amount, t.parentid
  from n
  join t on t.parentid = n.current_id
)
select t.id, t.name, t.amount, t.parentid,
  sum(n.amount) - t.amount as downstreamsum 
from t
join n on n.root_id = t.id
group by t.id, t.name, t.amount, t.parentid
order by t.id
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME   AMOUNT  PARENTID  DOWNSTREAMSUM 
--- ------ ------- --------- ------------- 
 1  Adam     1000         0          10700 
 2  John     2000         1           8700 
 3  Clark    1500         2           2800 
 4  Rita     1200         3              0 
 5  jack     1600         3              0 
 6  mark     1800         2           2600 
 7  Finn     1500         6              0 
 8  Ryan     1100         6              0
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e36f171ab769d2f7a883a06f232246a).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem here is you have created a table and the data I am getting is a result of multiple queries.
will it work for it as well?

Comment: @bhpsh You can place the last query as a vanilla CTE; then it would be easy to join it with any other tables or queries you need.

Comment: @bhpsh With the right indexes it should work well for a decent amount of data. But huge is a *big* word, pun intended. How many rows are you considering?

Answer (score 0):

This query also calculates own and child sums and count:

```sql
with mcnt (
    id, parentid, name, amount
    ,rnk
    ,level_members_cnt
    ,level_members_sum
    ,own_members_cnt
    ,own_members_sum
    ,child_members_cnt
    ,child_members_sum
    ) as (
   select 
          p.id, p.parentid, p.name, p.amount
        , row_number()over(partition by p.parentid order by p.id) rnk
        , sum((select count(*) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id))over(partition by p.parentid) as level_members_cnt
        , sum((select sum(m.amount) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id))over(partition by p.parentid) as level_members_sum
        , (select count(*) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id) as own_members_cnt
        , (select nvl(sum(m.amount),0) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id) as own_members_sum
        , 0 as child_members_cnt
        , 0 as child_members_sum
   from Hierarchy_result p
   where not exists(select null from Hierarchy_result child where p.id = child.parentid)
   union all
   select p.id, p.parentid, p.name, p.amount
        , row_number()over(partition by p.parentid order by p.id) rnk
        , sum((select count(*) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id))over(partition by p.parentid) level_members_cnt
        , sum((select sum(m.amount) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id))over(partition by p.parentid) level_members_sum
        , (select count(*) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id) as own_members_cnt
        , (select nvl(sum(m.amount),0) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id) as own_members_sum
        , mcnt.level_members_cnt + mcnt.child_members_cnt as child_members_cnt
        , nvl(mcnt.level_members_sum,0) + nvl(mcnt.child_members_sum,0) as child_members_sum
   from mcnt, Hierarchy_result p
   where mcnt.parentid=p.id
     and mcnt.rnk=1
)
select
       id, parentid, name, amount, child_members_cnt, own_members_cnt
      ,child_members_cnt+own_members_cnt as total_cnt
      ,child_members_sum,own_members_sum
      ,child_members_sum+own_members_sum as total_sum
from mcnt
order by id;
```

Full example with sample data:

```html
with Hierarchy_result ("ID", "NAME", "AMOUNT", "PARENTID") as (
    select 1, 'Adam', 1000, 0 from dual union all
    select 2, 'John', 2000, 1 from dual union all
    select 3, 'Clark', 1500, 2 from dual union all
    select 4, 'Rita', 1200, 3 from dual union all
    select 5, 'jack', 1600, 3 from dual union all
    select 6, 'mark', 1800, 2 from dual union all
    select 7, 'Finn', 1500, 6 from dual union all
    select 8, 'Ryan', 1100, 6 from dual
)
,mcnt (
    id, parentid, name, amount
    ,rnk
    ,level_members_cnt
    ,level_members_sum
    ,own_members_cnt
    ,own_members_sum
    ,child_members_cnt
    ,child_members_sum
    ) as (
   select 
          p.id, p.parentid, p.name, p.amount
        , row_number()over(partition by p.parentid order by p.id) rnk
        , sum((select count(*) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id))over(partition by p.parentid) as level_members_cnt
        , sum((select sum(m.amount) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id))over(partition by p.parentid) as level_members_sum
        , (select count(*) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id) as own_members_cnt
        , (select nvl(sum(m.amount),0) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id) as own_members_sum
        , 0 as child_members_cnt
        , 0 as child_members_sum
   from Hierarchy_result p
   where not exists(select null from Hierarchy_result child where p.id = child.parentid)
   union all
   select p.id, p.parentid, p.name, p.amount
        , row_number()over(partition by p.parentid order by p.id) rnk
        , sum((select count(*) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id))over(partition by p.parentid) level_members_cnt
        , sum((select sum(m.amount) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id))over(partition by p.parentid) level_members_sum
        , (select count(*) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id) as own_members_cnt
        , (select nvl(sum(m.amount),0) from Hierarchy_result m where m.parentid=p.id) as own_members_sum
        , mcnt.level_members_cnt + mcnt.child_members_cnt as child_members_cnt
        , nvl(mcnt.level_members_sum,0) + nvl(mcnt.child_members_sum,0) as child_members_sum
   from mcnt, Hierarchy_result p
   where mcnt.parentid=p.id
     and mcnt.rnk=1
)
select
       id, parentid, name, amount, child_members_cnt, own_members_cnt
      ,child_members_cnt+own_members_cnt as total_cnt
      ,child_members_sum,own_members_sum
      ,child_members_sum+own_members_sum as total_sum
from mcnt
order by id;
```

Result

```
 ID PARENTID NAME  CHILD_MEMBERS_SUM OWN_MEMBERS_SUM  TOTAL_SUM CHILD_MEMBERS_CNT OWN_MEMBERS_CNT  TOTAL_CNT
--- -------- ----- ----------------- --------------- ---------- ----------------- --------------- ----------
  1        0 Adam               8700            2000      10700                 6               1          7
  2        1 John               5400            3300       8700                 4               2          6
  3        2 Clark                 0            2800       2800                 0               2          2
  4        3 Rita                  0               0          0                 0               0          0
  5        3 jack                  0               0          0                 0               0          0
  6        2 mark                  0            2600       2600                 0               2          2
  7        6 Finn                  0               0          0                 0               0          0
  8        6 Ryan                  0               0          0                 0               0          0
```

ps. based on my another solution: [Hierarchical Query - Counting records that belongs to Parent and Child Places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851761/hierarchical-query-counting-records-that-belongs-to-parent-and-child-places/62855837#62855837)